# Replacing some values in a column based on another df with the same columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, merge

I would like to swiftly replace `NA` values in the vector `id` in `first` df based on `x0` column value in `second` df without long steps of merging and deleting columns. In other words `x0` is the common record identifier. Simple example is following:

```
first <- data.frame(x0=1:5,
                     x3=90:94,
                     id=c("a1","a2","a3",NA,NA))`
```

```
  x0 x3   id
1  1 90   a1
2  2 91   a2
3  3 92   a3
4  4 93 <NA>
5  5 94 <NA>`
```

```
second <- data.frame(x0=4:8,
                     x2=seq(104,108,1),
                     id=c("a4","a5","a6","a7","a8"))`
```

```
  x0  x2 id
1  4 104 a4
2  5 105 a5
3  6 106 a6
4  7 107 a7
5  8 108 a8`
```

The expected result would be:

```
  x0 x3 id
1  1 90 a1
2  2 91 a2
3  3 92 a3
4  4 93 a4
5  5 94 a5`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a *update-join* or a *gap-fill-join* which could be done like:

```
first$id  <- as.character(first$id)
second$id  <- as.character(second$id)

idx <- match(first$x0, second$x0) #Update join
idxn <- which(!is.na(idx))
first$id[idxn]  <- second$id[idx[idxn]]
first
#  x0 x3 id
#1  1 90 a1
#2  2 91 a2
#3  3 92 a3
#4  4 93 a4
#5  5 94 a5
```

Comment: Perfect, did exactly what I needed! Thank you